# Proper CMake project configuration

Tags: c++, cmake, project

I am looking for a guideline regarding handling files that are not source files.
My project is a simple OpenGL application which uses shaders which is built using CMake.
Shaders are in seperate files with .vert .frag extensions respectively and those files are together with others in "src" folder.

Now, these shader files are read when .exe runs I am using Microsoft's C++ compiler, which creates adjacent folder to my src called "build" and in this folder, there is a folder containing my executable called "Debug".

So the structure looks like this:

```
|
|-src: main.cpp, default_shader.vert, default_shader.frag, etc.
|-build
    |- Debug
         |- main.exe, [and here I need to have my shaders]
```

**My question is:** How do I automate in a neat way moving shader files from my source directory
to this Debug folder?

I was thinking of adding custom target that would run batch file or maybe changing storage of the shaders from files with .vert/frag to something different.

Comment: ***I was thinking of adding custom target that would run batch file*** That could work. For my old projects (some started in 2008) I have a custom target that populates a batch file with the file names of all the dependent dlls and adds commands to copy the dlls to the Debug, Release and RelWithDebInfo targets.

Comment: If you're only planing on using windows, this may be an ok idea; If you're planing on building this on non-windows platforms I strongly recommend using a cmake script file instead. (Also imho the syntax is much nicer in cmake...) How do you locate those files at runtime btw? Do you need the files to be available to the VS debugger or only after installation?

Comment: @fabian, no, I don't think I need them in debugger. They're just stored in strings for a while to give them to opengl. For locating, I use just a path like "shaders/shader.vert" and running .exe sets relative path to the place where it is, so they need to be where the executable is.

Comment: If you don't need to run the code from visual studio, just use `install` commands that put the exe and the files in the correct locations relative to each other. This won't allow you to run the program via visual studio, but the copy of the program created by executing the install target produces a working setup...